# A Blank WooCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce in conjunction with the Ark theme (a third-party theme) on our WordPress website. Things were working perfectly up until the last week or so when I noticed the issue of the checkout page being rendered as a blank page.

This error can be replicated through these series of steps:

1. Navigate to the [store](http://www.aspirepi.com/index.php/store)
2. Add any item(s) to the basket
3. When you've added an item from the storefront, you then hover over the basket icon in the header and click Checkout.
4. If you chose to view the basket instead when adding an item, just scroll down and click Proceed to Checkout.

After chatting with my server provider, it was brought to my attention that some PHP errors were being thrown up. Here is an example of the errors in question.

[image: image description]

It seems like there is a plugin conflict with Fresh Framework (a plugin required by the theme to work as intended). Disabling this particular plugin shows the checkout page fine, albeit with much of the styling of the website gone (which is not how I want things).

I have contacted both WooCommerce and the theme's developers for assistance. The former unwilling to help due to the use of a third party theme. The latter being particular slow in responding to my queries.

The theme and all plugins are up-to-date. I did notice the issue upon applying some updates to certain plugins but not the ones in question (WooCommerce/Fresh Framework). Additionally, bringing up the browser's developer console does show a JQuery error (Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:...) which I believe is related to the issue.

Any type of assistance would be greatly appreciated as the critical error is occurring on a live website and it is particularly crippling our chances of doing business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glimpse it s most probable that the plugin (fresh-framework) was recently updated...

Deactivating removes its functions,
enabling it includes the functions but breaks the page

Suggest to check the plugin's history and restore to a previous version.
If that's not possible you probably have to wait until they get the error fixed (or try to fix it yourself)
But as you see most probably the problem comes frm the fresh-framework update

PD: PHP Notice are not errors, the errors are only PHP Warning & PHP Error
As you see from the PHP warnings it seems that there is a problem with the filepath where it's trying to write
freshizer.php line 248

you can temporary check which path it tries to write to by adding a wordpress log message or echoing the path....

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but is there a way of checking a plugin's history within WordPress? Plus, how do I go about adding a wordpress log message or echoing the path?

Comment: Restoring a previous backup of that particular plugin did the trick. I cannot believe I had been working on the issue for more than a week now and did not even think of doing this. Thank you so much.

Comment: you're very welcome...
experience in debugging I guess hehe, comes with the time...

PD: debug in wordpress
wp-config.php: set
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
 and then:
error_log( $message ); in the PHP code... should write to wp/contents/debug.log

Comment: By the way: As a long term solution (to be able to make updates to the plugin) it would be valuable (also for the plugin developer) to check what caused the error: did the new plugin version require a new setting in its plugin adjustments which was not set yet? Or is it simply a bug (would be nice to let them know if it is so)? etc...

Comment: Oh right, I have done the WordPress log already. I didn't know about the echoing. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, I have let them know how I went about resolving the issue. Will follow up on that in order to get some more answers. Much appreciated.